# How to make upload multiple files in single form at Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload

I have product form that adding new item for sale in my e-commerce project, It has title, description, price, brand, size areas and I want add area for putting product images, I can upload single file with filefield in form but I need upload multiple files and insert to different relationship file model with my product model (product class gets images from different related class). How can I do it with single form? I think I am so close to solving but I am not right way.

I used betterforms module but I couldn't it.

## model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class ProductImage(models.Model):
   product_id = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Product")
   product_image = models.FileField(upload_to='product_images/')
   cover_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name="Upload Date")

class Product(models.Model):
   seller = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Seller")
   category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Category Name")
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name="Product Title")
   size = models.ForeignKey("Size", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Size")
   color = models.ForeignKey("Color", on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Color")
   last_used_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Last Used Date")
   description = RichTextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name="Created Date")
   product_image = models.ManyToManyField("ProductImage", verbose_name = "ProductImages")
```

I am not sure, It should be manytomanyfield?

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product, Category, Size, Color, Brand, Shipping, Comission, ProductImage
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["category","title", "description","price", "income", "active_product",]
        images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ["cover_image","product_image"]


class ProductMultiForm(forms.ModelForm):
        form_classes = {
            'product': ProductForm,
            'images': ProductImageForm,
        }
```

I just tried concatenate two classes.

There is so complicate.

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .forms import ProductForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Product, Category, Size, Color, Brand, Shipping, Comission, ProductImage
from .forms import ProductMultiForm
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, CreateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View

class ProductMultiForm(request):
    form = ProductMultiForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form['product'].save()
        images = form['images'].save(commit=False)
        product.seller = request.user
        product.save()

        images.save()
        messages.success(CreateView,"Product created successful!")
        return redirect("index")

        form = ProductMultiForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        images = form.save(commit=False)
        product.seller = request.user
        images.product_id = product.id
        product.save()
        images.save()
        messages.success(self,"Product created successful!")
        return redirect("index")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline formsets for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets